# Allow file_get_conents of files, but disallow browsing to directory?

Tags: php, apache

in my `public_html` folder, I have some code like this:

```
echo file_get_contents('files/123.txt');
```

Users can view text files from a subfolder. But, is it possible using apache to block incoming requests to the `files` folder via browser?

Comment: while the below 2 options will work,  the best idea is to keep them outside the web root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Apache configuration, you can add:

```
<Directory /path/to/files/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory

I believe allowing file_get_contents is a PHP concern, not an Apache concern.

But once you do this, make sure to remember to restart Apache!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the Directory and Deny Apache directives:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny

Good examples here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html